# Select query within a select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I want to compare new users to returning users in a table by month.  I have a table that contains each action with a username and a date stamp.

I can easily pull users that performed an action in, for example, January 2011.  To see see if each user is new I need to then run their username against all previous records (prior to January 2011).

In my fumblings I came up with the following:

```
  SELECT ini.username,
         MIN(ini.datetime) AS firstAction,
         COUNT(ini.datetime) AS numMonth,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM tableActions tot
           WHERE tot.username = ini.username
             AND tot.datetime < '201101%' 
             AND tot.datetime > '201001%') AS numTotal
    FROM tableActions ini
   WHERE DATETIME >= '201101%' 
     AND DATETIME < '201102%'
GROUP BY ini.username
ORDER BY firstAction
```

It doesn't error, but it doesn't finish either.  Seems to be quite intense.

Comment: What's your question? How to "fix" it? State your requirements.

Comment: Data type of the `datetime` column is... `varchar`? bad idea. Your query *should* be slow. If data type of the datetime column is `datetime` then I fail to understand what kind of comparison is `>= '201101%'`?

Comment: Agreed, what is the column declaration for "datetime" ?

Comment: The datetime column is varchar, I can fix that though, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal the questions is how can first query for all actions in January 2011, and then compare that number to all previous actions.  Basically, I'm looking for new users performing actions in January by eliminating anyone who has performed an action previously.  Hope that's better.

Comment: @TimCutting: Too localised. This is a "can't do it" post, but SO is not a help/support site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-write the query to be (assuming `tableactions.datetime` is a `DATETIME` data type):

```
   SELECT ini.username,
          MIN(ini.datetime) AS firstAction,
          COUNT(ini.datetime) AS numMonth,
          x.numTotal
     FROM tableActions ini
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tot.username,
                  COUNT(*) AS numTotal
             FROM tableActions tot
            WHERE tot.datetime > '2010-01-01'
              AND tot.datetime < '2011-01-01'
         GROUP BY tot.username) x ON x.username = ini.username
    WHERE ini.datetime BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-01-31'
 GROUP BY ini.username
 ORDER BY firstAction
```

Might help to have an index on `username` at a minimum, though a covering index using `username`, `datetime` is worth considering.

The `datetime` comparison looks suspect - `LIKE` is the only to support wildcards.

Comment: had the same thought - count(datetime) ?

Comment: datetime is varchar.  Should I work to fix that first and then try running the query?  Thank you.

Comment: Can't say if the query will work as-is but the idea is right. BTW you can use `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @Tim Cutting: Yes - it's not trivial to change things when you have data but proper data typing will make finding things easier/perform better.

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple table-to-itself join with a suitable where clause will be sufficient (this query is straight from my head, not tested):

```
SELECT    curr_activity.username, COUNT(prev_activity.username) AS did_something_in_the_past
FROM      tableActions AS curr_activity
LEFT JOIN tableActions AS prev_activity ON curr_activity.username = prev_activity.username 
WHERE     curr_activity.datetime >= '2011-01-01' AND curr_activity.datetime < '2011-02-01'
AND       prev_activity.datetime <  '2011-01-01' 
GROUP BY  curr_activity.username
```

Indexes do matter. You must index the `username` and `datetime` column, and the `datetime` column must be a `datetime` or a similar data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username,
MIN(datetime) AS firstAction,
MAX(datetime) AS numMonth,
COUNT(*) AS numTotal
GROUP BY ini.username
HAVING numTotal > 1 
WHERE DATETIME between '201001%' AND '201102%'
ORDER BY username
* I think this collapsed version is what you need ?
```

Comment: There's different date criteria - might be a typo, otherwise I agree

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM tableActions tot
       WHERE tot.username = ini.username
         AND tot.datetime < '201101%' 
         AND tot.datetime > '201001%'
```

with

```
SELECT 1
        FROM tableActions tot
       WHERE tot.username = ini.username
         AND tot.datetime < '201101%' 
         AND tot.datetime > '201001%' LIMIT 1
```

, so it does not have to loop through all the records and count them.

Comment: Yes, TOP is for SQL Server, so you need to use `LIMIT 1` in the end of you the sub-query instead. I am not a big expert on MySql, so just assume it will work.